# Django QuerySet: limiting results grouping by certain field

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I searched and couldn't find a way to do the following:

Suppose we have a Django model with the fields "field_a" and "field_b".
I want to limit the results in certain way that for each different value of "field_a" a maximum of N entries are retrieved from the model table. So, this is not a case of slicing the query set, since that would not make distinction of "field_a" values.

*PS: There's a way to do that using SQL.*

Lets use an example:

```
class ExampleModel(models.Model):
    foreign = models.ForeignKey(ForeignTable)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="user_attending")
```

Basically I want to do the following:

Find all the `ExampleModels` that have a certain id for `foreign_id` and `user_id`. But I only want to find at most 3 `user_id`'s from a list of `user_id`'s. So even if there're 20 matching `user_id`'s for a certain `foreign_id`, just give me the top three.

I appreciate the help!

EDIT:
It seems like my question is being misunderstood, so I'll provide an example. From:

```
foreign_id=1,user_id=1
foreign_id=1,user_id=2
foreign_id=1,user_id=3
foreign_id=1,user_id=4
foreign_id=2,user_id=5
foreign_id=2,user_id=6
foreign_id=2,user_id=3
foreign_id=2,user_id=2
foreign_id=3,user_id=1
foreign_id=3,user_id=9
```

The result would be, with only ONE Query set:

```
foreign_id=1,user_id=1
foreign_id=1,user_id=2
foreign_id=1,user_id=3
foreign_id=2,user_id=5
foreign_id=2,user_id=6
foreign_id=2,user_id=3
foreign_id=3,user_id=1
foreign_id=3,user_id=9
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use slicing
exemple:

```
ExampleModel.objects.filter(ForeignTable__id=1).order_by('id')[:3]
```

returns the first 3 object(limit 3)

Comment: But that means a new query for each different `ForeignTable__id`.

Comment: you can use complex query with Q object:                                example use And:                                                                   ExampleModel.objects.filter(Q(ForeignTable__id=1),Q(ForeignTable__id=2),Q(ForeignTable__id=3))                                                     see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/ for more information about Complex lookups with Q objects

Comment: But how the limit will be applied? It will not make distinction of the ids. That won't work.

Comment: why you don't use distinct()  ExampleModel.objects.filter(ForeignTable__id=1).order_by('id').distinct('id')[:3]

Comment: It won't work. The problem is that all the answers provided so far will only have 3 results. I guess everybody is misunderstanding the question. I want max 3 results for EACH id in only one query.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to do it in SQL, then I suggest that you add that constraint as an extra option to a django queryset, like in the accepted answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127379/tricky-django-genericrelation-query?rq=1)

See also the [Queryset extra documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra).

Comment: I knew that we can use SQL with Django query sets, but I'd rather use the API functions if they exist. Sorry if it was not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can try like this, For the following model:

```
class ExampleModel(models.Model):
    foreign = models.ForeignKey(ForeignTable)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="user_attending")
    time_created= models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


results= ExampleModel.objects.filter(foreign__id=1).annotate(time_created_max=Max('time_created')).order_by('time_created_max').distinct()

three_results= results[:3]
```

**PS:** `order_by` and `distinct` together can cause problems thus I attached another field. Reference [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#distinct).

Generally, slicing a QuerySet returns a new QuerySet – it doesn’t evaluate the query. Reference [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#limiting-querysets)

EDIT: I don't think requested process can be done by a single query.

```
data= [ ExampleModel.objects.filter(foreign_id=f)[0:2] for f in ForeignTable.objects.all()]
```

Comment: That's not exactly what I needed. I don't want to get results from a single `foreign_id`. This field is supposed to be the "grouper".